# How to write file path in elixir-iex? I am using windows

Tags: windows, elixir, elixir-iex

I wrote this:

```
File.read("C:\Users\Mostafiz\OneDrive\Desktop\New_Text_Document")
```

But getting the following error:

> {:error, :enoent}

I copied this file path from the properties that file.

> C:\Users\Mostafiz\OneDrive\Desktop

Now my question is, how to write this file path in elixir-iex?

Comment: Voted to close this question: It requires more information that replying "This solution didn't work" to every answer...

Comment: But I tried every solution, and every time I failed. I got the same error.

Comment: Probably there are two problems: 1) The \ is escaping the characters in the string. Since you said you tried the answers already and it still doesn't work, probably the other problem is 2) the file does not exist. Can you edit your question to demonstrate that the file exists?

Comment: I checked in the directory, the file exists. I think, I am not writing the path correctly. "C:\Users\Mostafiz\OneDrive\Desktop" I copied this file path from the properties that file. Now my question is, how to write this file path in elixir-iex?

Answer (score 1):

Elixir, like many other languages, interprets backspaces inside strings as escapes. Some of them have special meanings (like `\n` for a newline), but the ones that don't become the escaped character itself. So for example, `\U` becomes `U`. You can check this by writing `IO.puts <your string>` in `iex`, and you'll see that your backslashes disappear:

```
iex(1)> IO.puts "C:\Users\Mostafiz\OneDrive\Desktop\New_Text_Document"
C:UsersMostafizOneDriveDesktopNew_Text_Document
```

To get the path you want you need to either escape the backspash itself (writing `\\` in your string) or use forward slashes, since they are also recognized as path separators.

So either this:

```
iex(1)> IO.puts "C:\\Users\\Mostafiz\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\New_Text_Document"
C:\Users\Mostafiz\OneDrive\Desktop\New_Text_Document
```

Or this:

```
iex(1)> IO.puts "C:/Users/Mostafiz/OneDrive/Desktop/New_Text_Document"
C:/Users/Mostafiz/OneDrive/Desktop/New_Text_Document
```

Comment: This solution didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Always use [`~S`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_S/2) sigil for paths, it prevents string interpolation.

```elixir
iex||1 ▸ "C:\Users\Mostafiz\OneDrive\Desktop\New_Text_Document"
"C:UsersMostafizOneDriveDesktopNew_Text_Document"
iex||2 ▸ ~S"C:\Users\Mostafiz\OneDrive\Desktop\New_Text_Document"
"C:\\Users\\Mostafiz\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\New_Text_Document"
```

Comment: This solution didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you need to escape the forward slashes.

Does `File.read("C:\\Users\\Mostafiz\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\New_Text_Document")` work?

Comment: This solution didn’t work.